# make certain method when closing a window in GUI

Tags: java, swing

I've made a Notepad program and i wonder how can i create a popup window which pops up when i click on the "close" button and ask the user if he would like to save  the content which was written in the note pad.

I was think of **JOptionPane** as a solution but not sure how to add buttons to the window it creates and how to call the "popup" window.

[image: Here's how i expect my popup window to look like:]

Comment: in the actionPerformed linked to the 'close' button?

Answer (score 0):

write the code for showing JOptionPane object within the windowClosing(WindowEvent e){} method of the WindowListener interface by implementing the interface with the application's main class.

Visit this link for more information:
[Java windows listener interface methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to "listen" when the user closes the window (Clicks "X")   :

```
yourJFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {     
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                //your code , you can create the JOptionPane here.

        }
 });
```